Azure File Storage Premium Cost
We are already using Azure File Storage Premium. I was analyzing the bills. My bill is approx 200$. We checked azure calculator  it says 0 upfront cost and 0 upfront monthly cost. Egress, Ingress, Capacity cost etc are not mentioned. Any other link to calculate the cost?
As of now we are NOT creating any snapshots as well..



Premium Azure File shares are billed based on allocated/provisioned storage, not on used storage. So you are paying for whatever size you configured your file share/s to be, not what is actually being used. Please review details in the Data Storage section here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/files/
